# WebViewClient class overview?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

[WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) has an overview, which helps understand the purpose, expected flow and how to use it, but [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html), for some reason, doesn't have an overview.

What is the purpose of this class? Why have a separate class for the methods it contains? What is the typical/normal sequence of events in its lifetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the purpose of this class?

It allows your code to be informed of various events in the lifecycle of an associated `WebView`.

> Why have a separate class for the methods it contains?

It is a listener interface that you can attach to `WebView`, so you can get events through composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a "typical/normal" sequence of events in its lifetime?

Comment: @an00b: I have no idea. I have never considered it. If you must know, create a `WebViewClient` implementation that implements all callback methods and dumps each to LogCat, and see what happens.